# Passing R object (plot/image) to Python environment in Python

Tags: python, r, databricks

I am creating some plots using `ggplot2`in R which I would like to pass to the Python environment an eventually use a already developed script that writes the images to an excel.

Is this possible somehow in Databricks?

(I am aware of the `plotnine` packages in Python to create `ggplot2` imagine but I wish not to use it)

Comment: You can write an image in Excel with R. Would that be useful?

Comment: @emmanuelhamel no unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

In `Databricks`, you can use the `dbutils.fs` module to interact with the file system, including the ability to write and read files.

Given your requirement, you could generate your plots using `ggplot2` in `R`, save these plots as images, and write these image files to the Databricks File System (DBFS).

Then, you can read these image files into `Python`, and use them as you would use any other image data.